# How should I insulate an interior wall between a warm humid bathroom and a cold bedroom?

Tags: bathroom, insulation, interior

We're redoing the master bath. I'm wondering if and how I should insulate the interior wall. Bedroom is kept at 60F. Bathroom will be warm (radiant floor) and humid even if we have and run vent fan.

Should I put insulation in wall? Standard fiberglass with vapor barrier on bathroom side? Foam board? Fiberglass w/o vapor barrier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given what you know about how you will heat the rooms differentially, insulation is good. I'd go with mineral wool (or fiberglass) since some **sound** isolation is often desirable between bedroom and bathroom and foam is not great at that application.

If you will be doing the bathroom walls with a moisture barrier no additional vapor barrier on the insulation is called for.

Comment: Seems reasonable but note that this is the opposite of the answer given here: http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/63994/is-some-condensation-on-bathroom-walls-safe

Comment: @mankoff - read more carefully.

Comment: "if doing walls with vapor barrier" - meaning if I do not, I should do vapor barrier on the insulation, correct? The other answer seems to say *not* to do vapor barrier in the wall. I've read both, and again carefully now, but I think I'm still missing something...

Comment: No! No vapor barrier! Anywhere! Ever! They are just a terrible idea. Do NOT put a dedicated plastic vapor barrier behind your drywall; not in a bathroom, not in a living room, not anywhere! I do not want it, Sam I Am!

Comment: What about with an exterior wall? No vapor barrier there either?